# unresolved import `pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight`

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-contracts

Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/home/briza/Desktop/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
Using rustc version: rustc 1.67.0-nightly (c97b539e4 2022-11-30)

I followed this doc: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/ , and when I worked in this step "Implement the Contracts configuration trait", and I use th
cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release

the terminal showed that

> error[E0432]: unresolved import `pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight`

more information below:

> Information that should be included in a bug report.
> Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/home/briza/Desktop/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
> Using rustc version: rustc 1.67.0-nightly (c97b539e4 2022-11-30)
> --- stderr
> Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/briza/Desktop/substrate-node-template/runtime)
> error[E0432]: unresolved import `pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight`
> --> /home/briza/Desktop/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:47:5
> |
> 47 | use pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight;
> |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `DefaultContractAccessWeight` in the root
> error[E0437]: type `ContractAccessWeight` is not a member of trait `pallet_contracts::Config`
> --> /home/briza/Desktop/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:167:3
> |
> 167 |   type ContractAccessWeight = DefaultContractAccessWeight;
> |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `pallet_contracts::Config`
> error[E0437]: type `RelaxedMaxCodeLen` is not a member of trait `pallet_contracts::Config`
> --> /home/briza/Desktop/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:169:3
> |
> 169 |   type RelaxedMaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 512 * 1024 }>;
> |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `pallet_contracts::Config`
> Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0437.
> For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am getting a similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. The following steps helped me resolve it.

First, I removed the import of `pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight`

I added this line `pub const DeletionQueueDepth: u32 = 128;` to `parameter_types!`. So your new block should look something like this

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub const DepositPerItem: Balance = deposit(1, 0);
    pub const DepositPerByte: Balance = deposit(0, 1);
    pub const DeletionQueueDepth: u32 = 128;
    pub const UnsafeUnstableInterface: bool = false;
    pub DeletionWeightLimit: Weight = AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO * BlockWeights::get().max_block;
    pub Schedule: pallet_contracts::Schedule<Runtime> = Default::default();
}
```

Finally I changed the arguments `Config`. The final code looks like

```rust
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type CallFilter = frame_support::traits::Nothing;
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 31];
    type DeletionQueueDepth = DeletionQueueDepth;
    type DeletionWeightLimit = DeletionWeightLimit;
    type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
    type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
    type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
    type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 256 * 1024 }>;
    type MaxStorageKeyLen = ConstU32<{ 512 * 1024 }>;
    type UnsafeUnstableInterface = UnsafeUnstableInterface;
    type MaxDebugBufferLen = ConstU32<{ 256 * 1024 }>;
}
```

It is possible that this code may not work in the future. All you need to do is the go the source code of the `pallet_contracts` and add/remove the argument according to the code. Use dummy argument. The compiler's debugger will do a good job in directing you to the right code.